# Deleted audio still plays in preview

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I have deleted some audio and the deleted audio plays **only** in the preview not the render.

I have tried disabling caching but the problem still occurs. I posted on Reddit and no one helped me. You can find the video with sound in this post:

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/1005fn4/deleted_audio_still_plays/

Comment: try saving as a new file. can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com